# Getting double values out of a jtable

Tags: java, swing, casting, jtable

I found a few threads with a similar problem, but nothing worked for me.
I'm trying to get a double and a string value out of a jtable.
I'm using the DefaultTableModel and did override the getCOlumnClass method:

```
private void initTable()
{
    String tableColumns[] = { language.getTranslatedPhrase(MultilanguageUtil.Amount),
            language.getTranslatedPhrase(MultilanguageUtil.Ingredient),
            language.getTranslatedPhrase(MultilanguageUtil.Unit) };

    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(tableColumns, 0) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
         @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {  
                switch (column) {  
                    case 0:
                        return Double.class;
                    case 1:  
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:  
                        return Units.class; 
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }  
       }
    };


    table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

I'm expecting double values in the first column, but when i try to get a value with:

```
int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount - 1; i++)
{
    double doubleValue = (Double) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I have also tried this:

```
Object objValue = tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
        double doubleValue = ((Double) objValue).doubleValue();
```

but i get the same exception.

when i excecute

```
System.out.println(table.getColumnClass(0));
```

it says

```
class java.lang.Double
```

so, it seems to be right, but i still get the exception, which says that its an integer, and i can't cast it to a double...

I hope someone could help me, and sorry for my bad english!(not my first language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to fix the error you should not put `Integer`s to the cell that you explicitly defined to have `double` values. You can work around it like this: use `String.valueOf()` to make a `String` from your input. This method accepts many variable types. Then from `String`, you can `Double.parseDouble()`. For example

```
double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0)));
```

Is a bit hackey but works.

Comment: Thank you very much! When i make sure, that the values in the cells are actually double values this works without problems: `double doubleValue = (double) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);` Your solution worked well, but i think i should make sure that there are actually double values in the cells.